# Java WebDriver connection refused

Tags: java, android, node.js, selenium-webdriver, appium

When Appium server is started via script, Appium server is successfully started as per logs, but it throws a connection refused for WebDriver. For the script, I am trying to run testng.xml file on  android device.
Error Logs :

> ```
> [main] INFO  com.****.common.BaseTest  - ###### Appium Server Started ######
>
> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
> Host info: host: 'MAC-a13403723', ip: '2409:40d0:10c3:c210:85f:609c:f13a:6059%en0'
>
>   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:553)
>   at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:229)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:156)
>   at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:80)
>   at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:92)
>   at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:117)
>   at com.airtelafrica.common.BaseTest.initialization(BaseTest.java:69)
>   at com.airtelafrica.common.BaseTest.opcoChooser(BaseTest.java:86)
>   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
>   at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:132)
>   at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:61)
>   at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:366)
>   at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:320)
>   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:327)
>   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
>   at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
>   at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
>   at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1218)
>   at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1213)
>   at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
>   at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1069)
>   at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1037)
>   at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
>   at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:105)
> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Connection refused
> Build info: version: '4.7.2', revision: '4d4020c3b7'
> System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version: '12.6.8', java.version: '11.0.21'
> Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
>   at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.lambda$execute$4(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:274)
>   at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
>   at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:273)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:535)
>   ... 26 more
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
>   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:777)
>   at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:337)
>   at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
>   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776)
>   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
>   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
>   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
>   at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
>   at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
>   at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
>   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
> ```

System : Mac OS
Device: One Plus
Java: 11
Node: v18.18.2
Appium: Appium v2.1.3
IntelliJ
Maven

All the capabilities are being sent via config.properties file. I am able to see device which I need to run under 'adb devices' list. I'm trying to run Appium on an Android device and unable to start session on device although Appium is started.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!